# Firebase Push Notification (FCM)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am implementing firebase push notifications using flutter. Is there a way to get the notification real time or a few milliseconds delay?

Anyone can help me?

Push notifications from firebase received with a delay of more than a minute.

Comment: Check your Firebase Server location and the device location. Firebase Server location which you have selected while creating the project. Also check Firebase Functions .region()  value if you are using Firebase Functions to send the message. More the distance between server and device location, it is likely you get message late.

Answer (score -1):

You can send a notification either using a specific FCM Token or to a user segment to all users of the app or a topic. In my experience, a general notification to a user segment takes quite some time which is quite annoying.

This is why when I am building an app and want to test notifications I use the FCM token of my testing device to directly send notifications. It is quite instantaneous. To get token of your test device you can use this code as a reference:

```dart
  // *Get Token

  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  var storageProvider = StorageProvider();
  String? token;
  if (storageProvider.read('firebase_token') == null) {
    token = await messaging.getToken();
    storageProvider.write('firebase_token', token);
    log('FCM Token From Web: $token');
  } else {
    token = storageProvider.read('firebase_token');
    log('FCM Token From Storage: $token');
  }
```

I hope it's helpful to you.